# Spring MVC - Error instantiating servlet class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying to learn Spring MVC and have gotten into some problems. I suppose there is something wrong either in my web.xml or servlet-config.xml files. When I type localhost:8080/FitnessTracker/greeting.html I get the following error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class
>   org.springframwork.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

My `web.xml` file below:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframwork.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My `servlet-config.xml` file below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.pluralsight.controller"></context:component-scan>

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        </bean> 

        <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
</beans>
```

My controller:

```
package com.pluralsight.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")
    public String sayHello(Model model){

        model.addAttribute("greeting", "hello world!");


        return "Hello"; 
    }


}
```

[image]

[image]

What could possible be wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The servlet file name should be fitTrackerServlet-servlet.xml.

Comment: Still same error,...

Comment: 1. Have you added Spring Wed maven dependencies in pom.xml ? 2. have you installed project using maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the servlet class with the below code in web.xml

```
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
```

You mentioned the wrong package name. Check the spelling of springframework in `<servlet-class>`in `web.xml` servlet mappings.

If java 8 is used, upgrade to spring version 4 to resolve any incompatibility issues

Comment: Now I'm gettings this error:  Servlet.init() for servlet fitTrackerServlet threw exception

Comment: Please add the full stack trace

Comment: which version of spring and java  you are using?

Comment: IF you are using Java 8, then upgrade to spring 4 release.

Comment: Hi! Im using java 8 and spring 3.2. Will upgrade to spring 4 and see if the problem remains.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for the answer. The problem is now solved when i upgraded to spring 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line

```
localhost:8080/FitnessTracker/greeting.html
```

with this

```
localhost:8080/FitnessTracker/greeting
```

try to add the backslash like this in web.xml

```
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: @mrjasmin see the modification of my answer

Answer (score -2):

**Solved.** My controller returned "Hello" instead of "hello" which is the name of the jsp file I want to show.

Comment: You're right. AFAIK, File names aren't case-sensitive.